# After a few hours or a few hours after

Tags: grammar, prepositions, conjunctions

Which of these is correct and why?

However, after a few hours of opening an incident occurred.

or

However, a few hours after opening an incident occurred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on context.

The form "after a few hours of opening" seems to imply that the process of opening had been ongoing for a few hours. It might be the case for a flower, for example, where the process can take hours.

The form "a few hours after opening" would be appropriate in, for example, the case of a store opening at 9AM. A few hours later something happened.